# How to stylize table <td> based on its value from ajax with datatables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a page showing datatables using php. As the data is increasing day by day, I have considered datatable ajax function to get it processed server side to reduce time taken to load all the data at once.

But the problem is I can't figure out how to style  based on its values. For example:

> What I'm using with PHP:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Amt</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php while ($data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
  echo "


<tr>
      <td>".$data->date."</td>
      <td>".$data->amt."</td>";

      // Please note this step...
      if ($data->status == "Paid") {
       echo '
        <td>
          <label class="label label-succcess">'.$data->status.'</label>
        </td>';
       }
      elseif ($data->status == "Unpaid"){
       echo '
        <td>
         <label class="label label-danger">'.$data->status.'</label>
        </td>';
      }
      elseif ($data->status == "Pending"){
       echo '
        <td>
         <label class="label label-warning">'.$data->status.'</label>
        </td>';
      }
echo '</tr>';
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

> How to achieve the same `<label>` style on `<td>` with data from
>   datatables ajax:

```
<table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amt</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>




$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#datatable-buttons').DataTable( {
    var table = $('#datatable-ajax').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
        "url": "scripts/json.php",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "date" },
        { "data": "amt" },
        { "data": "status" },
    ]
} );
```

Comment: Short answer is there are rendering callbacks you can use that give you access to the row data and row elements. These get configured in your options object. Search "render" in the docs reference

Answer (score 0):

Add following function to $(document).ready(function() { . I have kept 3 seconds delay to take care of ajax. You can adjust the same.

```
            setTimeout(
            function() 
            {
              //do something special
              $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
                //alert($(this).text());
                if($(this).text() === "Paid" ){
                    $(this).addClass('label label-succcess');
                }
                else if($(this).text() === "Unpaid" ) {
                    $(this).addClass('label label-danger');
                }
                else if($(this).text() === "Pending" ) {
                    $(this).addClass('label label-warning');
                }
              });
            }, 3000);
```